# Как запустить через cron каждую секунду

Tags: cron

Имеется VPS с Ubuntu 18/
нужно запустить cron что бы каждую секунду запускался
/usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null -q "https://kino.com/engine/ajax/controller.php?mod=collaps"
то есть каждую секунду шел запрос на 
https://kino.com/engine/ajax/controller.php?mod=collaps
но крон минимум раз в минуту срабатывает. есть решение альтернативное?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Просто без крона запустить скрипт с вечным циклом и sleep 1

Comment: подскажи как правильно это сделать? я в это не силен (

Answer (score 0):

Альтернативное решение systemd сервис.time

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/469251)

Comment: в конце своего вопроса - автор спросил про альтернативное решение

Comment: несколько неправильный коммент оставил, извините) Имел ввиду, что ответ необходимо расширить, ведь автор может и не знать, что такое systemd сервис.time